# why my if block is not executed in cshtml file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, pagination

**here i am calling a partial view in main page admin.cshtml and partial view is user.cshtml through ajax**

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-md-9 w-100" id="loadPartialView">
                @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_userpage.cshtml")
            </div>
```

**here i am loading all partial view whenever i am clicking the link on sidebar of admin.cshtml**

**now whenver i am calling user.cshtml and when the count of user is 0 than this if block is not displayed in main admin.cshmtl page when code is executed**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   
    @if (Model.users.Count() == 0)
     {
        <div class="d-flex mt-5 flex-column" id="nouser">
        <div class="mx-auto"><h3>No user found</h3></div>
        </div>
        }
    else
      {
    <table class="table">
        @if (Model.users.Count() == 0)
     {
        <div class="d-flex mt-5 flex-column" id="nouser">
        <div class="mx-auto"><h3>No user found</h3></div>
        </div>
        }
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Firstname</th>
                <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                <th scope="col">Employee id</th>
                <th scope="col">Department</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var user in Model.users)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@user.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@user.LastName</td>
                    <td>@user.Email</td>
                    <td>@user.EmployeeId</td>
                    <td>@user.Department</td>
                </tr>
            }
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center page">
        @if (Model.users.PageCount > 1)
        {
            <ul class="pagination use">

                @if (Model.users.HasPreviousPage && Model.users.PageNumber > 1)
                {
                    <li class="page-item"> <a class="page-link" id="@Convert.ToInt32(@Model.users.PageNumber -1)"> &#60;&#60; </a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="page-item"> <a class="page-link disabled" id="@Convert.ToInt32(@Model.users.PageNumber -1)"> &#60;&#60; </a></div>
                }
                @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.users.PageCount; i++)
                {
                    if (i == Model.users.PageNumber)
                    {
                        <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" id="@i">@i</a></li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="@i">@i</a></li>
                    }

                }
                @if (Model.users.HasNextPage && Model.users.PageNumber < Model.users.PageCount)
                {
                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" id="@Convert.ToInt32(@Model.users.PageNumber + 1)"> >></a></li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="page-item"><a class="page-link disabled" id="@Convert.ToInt32(@Model.users.PageNumber + 1) "> >></a></div>
                }
            </ul>
        }
    </div>
    }
</div>
```

**this is the code that i ma displaying and this the ajax result for it the result is perfect but only when count is 0 nothing is appering not even no user found div**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/User",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            SearchInputdata: keyword,

        },
        success: function (response) {
            alert('called');
            console.log(response);
            console.log("the id element", $(response).find("#nouser").html());
            $('#nouser').html($(response).find('#nouser').html());
            $('.table').empty().html($(response).find('.table').html());
            $('.pagination').empty().html($(response).find('.pagination').html());
           
        }
    })
```

**what is the problem with this?**

Comment: Not quite sure, it's a bit difficult to to follow. That said, in your AJAX call's success handler, it looks like you are getting the `nouser` element's HTML from the response and attempting to place it in the `nouser` element's HTML that you expect to already exist on the page. I don't think you have the `nouser` element on the page so your AJAX success handler can't locate the element and update the HTML. So, are you sure your `nouser` element exists on the page at the time the AJAX success handler is run? This line is in question... `$('#nouser').html($(response).find('#nouser').html());`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think above code is getting really quite crazy and hard to follow.
It's pretty hard to work out what is going on and the issue that you have.

I think in the core of what your doing is displaying a list of something and then wanting to paginatate that with ajax.

Essentially you have the right approach, load in a Model and use the PartialView to show the data that you want. But after that is where you run into the problems.

**Issue 1.**
So rather than use your own pagination I would use something like X.PagedList it's super simple and easy to set up.
Code like this would help.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Supervisions,
            page => Url.Action("MyAction", new { searchParam = Model.MySearch page }),
            PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new PagedListRenderOptions {  UlElementClasses = new[] { "pagination pagination-sm" } },new AjaxOptions()
            {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                UpdateTargetId = "loadPartialView",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace

            })
    )
```

`loadPartialView` is the outside element id and `myAction` is an action that would send back the partialView. In your case it would go to `/Admin/User` and your controller might use the `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` to determine the request type.

**Issue 2.**
I wouldn't use your own code and use the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` should just plug and play with the pagination you have created.

After that it should all work.